# Saving the file 'web.config' requires you to stop your debug session error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-config

I'm trying to make changes to web.config after running the application. It gives the following error.

> Saving the file 'web.config' requires you to stop your debug session.
>   Would you like to stop debugging now?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

[image]

I thought it has to do something with `Enable Edit and Continue` feature in visual studio. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @WeTTTT - we recently switched to VS2012 from VS2010. I used to be able to change web.config without this error.

Comment: I was wrong. Both VS2012 and VS2010 are able to keep debugger attached when directly save web.config as I tested on VS2010 & VS2012 on IIS7. Are you using IIS7/7.5/8 or IIS Express for debugging?

Comment: That's quite strange. I cannot recreate this here. Is it possible that you(or someone else) was holding a breakpoint when you were trying to save the web.config?

Comment: @WeTTTT - No. There aren't any breakpoints.

Comment: Are you sure you are using IIS and visual studio internal development web server?

Comment: Why did you need that? I'm just curious

Comment: @Kuzgun - we use web.config to add users to our internal Web Application (not Website) manually by using custom tags `<user id="someID" pwd="somePWD" />`. I used to be able to add/edit/delete them without stopping debug mode.

Comment: I was having the exact same issue after upgrading to VS2013, however disabling `Enable Edit and Continue` **did** do the trick

Comment: Different option is to edit the file outside of Visual Studio. Really no reason at all it does this.

Answer (score 11):

I just want to add something to the comment that janv8000 made about Edit and Continue, because I've just been having the same problem and managed to sort it.

To give some background, I had an existing web application, created in VS 2012. When I debug this project in VS 2013, I can edit the web.config file happily without restarting the debugger. I then created a new web application in VS 2013, and found that I got the error message in the original question when I tried to edit the web.config file.

The solution to this was to disable Edit and Continue **for the individual project**. The reason I highlight this is because there's a global debugger setting in Tools->Options->Debugger for Edit and Continue. This is not the option that causes this problem.

To solve it:

1. Go to the project preferences for your web application (right click on it in the solution explorer and go to "Properties").
2. Go to the "Web" tab.
3. At the bottom of this tab is a section called "Debuggers".
4. Uncheck "Enable Edit and Continue".

Answer (score 1):

First off let me point out a quick fact. There are two different types of projects here.

1. A `WebSite` which is created by select `New WebSite` from the Visual Studio menu.
2. A `WebApplication` which is created by selecting `New Project` and selecting `ASP.Net Web Forms Appplication`

Now the reason to point this is out is simple.

The first option allows you to change your web.config without performing an Application reset *(only while Debugging)*. This is because the `WebSite` project files are compiled as the pages \ files are requested. Therefore everytime you request a page the code is compiled. This is also why you can change code files while debugging with no problems.

The second type is a compiled application. Therefore all the code is compiled before runtime. In this scenario the AppPool (IIS, IISExpress) watches for changes to this file. If changes happen to this file the application MUST restart in order for changes to take affect. Now there is no way to stop this behavior as its part of the core `AppPool`.

Here is an excerpt from MSDN:

> **Configuration Changes Cause a Restart of the Application Domain**
>
> Changes to configuration settings in Web.config files indirectly cause
>   the application domain to restart. This behavior occurs by design. You
>   can optionally use the configSource attribute to reference external
>   configuration files that do not cause a restart when a change is made.
>   For more information, see configSource in General Attributes Inherited
>   by Section Elements.
>
> Attempts to change a configuration file by
>   someone who does not have permission to edit the file will not cause a
>   restart of the application domain.

Full MSDN page. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7.aspx

As it states here there is one way around it. By using the `configSource` to reference external configuration files which you may change without a problem.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Ours is a web application. I'm guessing there are certain config values which can be edited without restarting app domain but some are not(may be I'm completely wrong !!)

Comment: I don't see how this is possible.. Not a single test across multiple VS versions and projects have yielded the result. No parts of the web.config may be changed with out an app restart.

Comment: While i understand the explanation, my question is: Why this behaviour started only AFTER switching from VS2012 to VS2013? I was able to edit the web.config when using VS2012 without the need to restart the dubugging session.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this issue too after I switched from VS2012 to VS2013. I have two projects in a solution: a ASP.NET MVC application (created in VS2012) and ASP.NET Web API application (created in VS2013). For some reason, when I'm debugging the MVC app, Visual Studio does not complain if I edit web.config file for the MVC app, but it complains if do the same for Web API app while debugging it.

Comment: We still don't have the real explanation of why this behaviour have changed in VS2013. I didnt had this problem with VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012!

Comment: –1 this post's conclusion is false. using external source configs just means the host doesn't know it *should* restart. You can edit the file outside of VS and it can restart with the debugger attached, without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same problem on a Web Application using Visual Studio 2013. Before then I was using VS2010 and had no problem as you mentioned.

The solution I found is not to use IIS Express (: (I couldn't figure a way with using IIS Express)

1- Just right click on your project and select Properties.

2- On the "Web" tab, choose "Local IIS" under "Servers" section on the page.

3- Click on "Create Virtual Directory" button.

Viola, now you've deployed it on iis with port 80. (So it will be under "Default Web Site" section when you run inetmgr (IIS Manager), of course if you dont have any other site running on port 80)

**If you want a custom port (i.e. 1234):**

Just create new site on IIS Manager with the port 1234, then edit your url in project property in VS2013 as: "`http://localhost:1234/Your.Project.Name`"

If anyone shows how to edit and continue web.config using IIS Express, it will also be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I just added if this is still an issue for you. I'm using IIS Express and can edit the web.config file now that I've disabled Edit and Continue.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error in VS 2019. the following fixed it for me:
Go to the Debugging Browsers list (as in the screen shot), open the dropdown > script debugging, and disable it:

[image]